# Parent div size bug on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm working on a design and I get it OK on Chrome and IE, but not on Firefox.
The code is pretty long so I have created an example here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KHAbq).

The problem is about the comments container as you can see on the images below:

**Correct version**
[image: Correct version]

**Firefox version**
[image]

Any idea about this problem?

Thanks by advance, Valentin

Comment: Which Firefox do you use? It looks fine on FF 27.0.1.

Comment: Tried this on FF 28 and it looks good.

Comment: I can't check now as I'm not at work anymore. However, I installed it today and took the latest version for Windows 7 so it should be FF29... 
[edit] I just tried at home with FF29 on Windows 7, it works. So I'm sorry guys but I have to wait Friday to give you more details about it. But it definitely looks like a weird problem.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that my Firefox at work is FF29 on Windows 7 and I do have the problem of box size...

Comment: Well, it appears it was a cache problem! :/ How to actually work without cache in Firefox? I tried to activate the option in devtools but it doesn't works for HTML template loaded asynchronously...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` to the comment box.